# Two semi transparent rectangle that overlap without changing the common area color

Tags: swift, core-graphics, calayer, quartz

I have a lot of CALayer, each with a semitransparent green rectangle inside. When I add all these layers onto a view layer, the common area change color, as you can see in the figure.

Is there any simple way to avoid this without having to look for intersection every time I add a layer to the view?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this helps, but if your rectangles are going to be the same color (in this case the same color green), then:

1. Wrap all of the green rectangles in a parent DIV
2. Set the opacity on the parent container to the semi-transparent value you
   want to have for the rectangles (e.g. 30%)
3. Set the opacity of the individual child rectangles to 100%, since the semi-transparency is achieved through the opacity of the parent container

**Result**: The rectangles will be semi-transparency, but the opacities will not multiply when they rectangles overlap.

Comment: Good idea, I will try.

Comment: In the code, wrote time ago, I used a CAMutableLayer which a rebuild when adding the second rectangle, so to have only one shape (and consequently a uniform color). Since my solution works I have still not tried yours (sorry) but I will try soon or later and then I will tell you!